# Approximate Maclaurin series for $\sqrt x$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, radicals

One of my hobbies for the past while has been Taylor and Maclaurin series. I understand that since $ f(x)=\sqrt x $ isn't analytic at zero, we can't make a Maclaurin series expansion for it.

However, after some playing around, I was able to construct a Maclaurin series which closely approximates square root of x. It isn't obvious to me why this function should exist (I tried searching for it), and I was hoping someone more knowledgeable could explain, or point me in the right direction at the very least. The function is: $$f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n (-1)^n}{n! (1-2n)}$$ Here's a plot for reference :) [Approximate Maclaurin series for sqrt(x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Us08.png)

**Edits after some insight from Goncalo, I think I understand. I'll construct the approximation, but first some foreground**
The $\sqrt x \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt x) $ term seemed mysterious, and led me down a rabbit hole. I initally assumed that given an analytic function $ f(x) $, $ f(\sqrt x)$ wouldn't have a Maclaurin series representation because $ \sqrt x $ isn't analytic at zero.

However, as long as $ f(x) $ is an even function, we're in luck! Consider $$ f(x) = \cos(\sqrt x) $$ We could write this as
$$ \cos(\sqrt x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^\frac{n}{2} \operatorname{t}(n)}{n!} $$ Where
$ \operatorname{t}(n) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}n)$
Now, since cosine is an even function, all the fractional power terms are cancelled (!!), meaning we can rearrange to
$$ \cos(\sqrt x) =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n \operatorname{t}(2n)}{n! \operatorname{P}(n,2n)} $$
Where $\operatorname{P}(k,x)$ is the falling factorial:
$$ \operatorname{P}(k,x) = \prod_{m=0}^{k-1}x-m$$  Interestingly, this lets us find values for imaginary numbers, and smoothly [extends the domain for $ \cos(\sqrt x) $ into the negative reals.](https://i.imgur.com/oNrkcET.png) We can use this trick on the integral of $ \operatorname{erf}(x) $ like so. **First, set up this ugly but useful Maclaurin series, which represents the J$ _{th} $ integral of the Gaussian $ e^{-x^2} $**
$$ \operatorname{t}(n,J) = \left\{n+\operatorname{mod}\left(J,2\right)=1:0,\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(n-J\right)\right)P\left(\frac{n+1-J}{2},n+1-J\right)}{n+1-J}\right\} $$

Let $ \operatorname{even}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n t(n,2)}{n!} $. This is the second integral of the Gaussian.
Notice that if you normalize this function like so: $\frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}(2\operatorname{even}(x)-1)$ , it approximates $\operatorname{y}=x$. But we'll leave it for now.

Since $ \operatorname{even}(x) $ is an even function, we can use our trick to find $ \operatorname{even}(\sqrt x) $

We'll set up a new Maclaurin series based on our first one:
$$ \operatorname{u}(n) = \frac{\operatorname{t}(2n, 2)}{P(n,2n)} $$

Now, we have $ \operatorname{even}(\sqrt x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n \operatorname{u}(n)}{n!}$

All that's left to do is normalize, and we get
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt \pi}(2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n \operatorname{u}(n)}{n!}-1) \approx \sqrt x $$
If anyone finds this interesting, [here's a Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/olpqmiufqb)

Comment: A general complex analysis fact you could prove: if $f(z)$ is analytic on some open disk $D(0,r) \subset \mathbb{C}$ and is even ($f(z) = f(-z)$), then there exists a function $g$, analytic on $D(0, r^2)$, such that $g(z^2) = f(z)$.  You can think informally that $g(z) = f(\sqrt{z})$.

Comment: Did some more work. Given a list of coefficients $\operatorname{t}(n)$ such that $\operatorname{f}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\operatorname{t}(n)$, I was able to derive a formula for $\operatorname{f}(\sqrt(x))$. Note that $\operatorname{P}(k,x)$ is the falling factorial.

$$\operatorname{f}(\sqrt(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}(\frac{\operatorname{t}(2n)}{\operatorname{P}(n,2n)} + \frac{2\sqrt(x)\operatorname{t}(2n+1)}{\operatorname{P}(n+1,2(n+1))})$$

The 1st term contains all the even terms of the series, and the 2nd term contains all the odd terms.

Comment: The formula is right, but it has kind of a mistake. Makes more sense to write as
$$\operatorname{f}(\sqrt(x)) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}(\frac{\operatorname{t}(2n)}{\operatorname{P}(n,2n)} + \frac{\sqrt(x)\operatorname{t}(2n+1)}{\operatorname{P}(n+1,2n+1)})$$

Comment: To atone for my mistake, I constructed a more general formula:
$$ \operatorname{f}(x^\frac{1}{R}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}(\sum_{m=0}^{R-1}\frac{x^\frac{m}{R}\operatorname{t}(Rn+m)}{\operatorname{P}((R-1)n+m,Rn+m)}) $$

where R is a positive integer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Fsqrt%28pi%29*sum+%28-1%29%5Enx%5En%2F%28n%21%281-2n%29%29+from+n%3D0..infty), your series is equal to the function
$$
g(x)=\sqrt{x}\,\text{erf}(\sqrt{x})+\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \tag{1}
$$
where $\text{erf}$ is the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html). Its asymptoptic series is given by
$$
\text{erf}(x)\sim 1-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)\right)\qquad(x\gg 1). \tag{2}
$$
Substituting $x$ with $\sqrt{x}$ in $(2)$ and plugging the resut in $(1)$ yields
$$
g(x)\sim\sqrt{x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)\qquad(x\gg 1), \tag{1}
$$
which explains why your series is a good approximation to $\sqrt{x}$ for $x\gg 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$g(x) = \frac{f(x^2)}x-\frac1{x\sqrt{\pi}} = \frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}(-1)^{n-1}}{n!(2n-1)}$$
satisfies
$g(0) = 0$ and
$$g'(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-2}(-1)^{n-1}}{n!} = -\frac1{x^2\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!} = -\frac1{x^2\sqrt{\pi}}(e^{-x^2}-1)$$
so that
$$g(x) = \frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x \frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t^2}\,dt$$
and your claim (that $f(x)$ closely represents $\sqrt{x}$) is the fact that
$\varphi(t) = \frac{1-e^{-t^2}}{t^2}$ quickly goes to $0$ along with the fact
$$\sqrt{\pi} = \int_0^\infty \varphi(t)\,dt$$

Comment: Technically, $g(0)$ doesn't exist. You mean $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)=0$$

Comment: @KamalSaleh If you want to think of it that way, then you can.  Or you can, as I use it in the rest of the solution, define $g$ by the power series.  Or you can just follow the convention that functions should be defined at removeable singularities by removing them.  It doesn't matter to me how we get to that point.